# Create pandas dateframe with .apply

Tags: python, pandas

My research centers around working with Lidar point cloud data. The data that is acquired is X, Y, Z, R, G, B values. These values are in, as far as I can tell, random order when exported. Also, the rows and columns are not all the same size. The "extra" will be filled with a default value (zero in the code below). I have decided to use Pandas because I can set the index and column names/values to the Z and X coordinates (not possible with numpy). This allows me to avoid loops (for scaling reasons) by assigning the value with [.set_value](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html) method (I know this is depreciated but it is ~3x faster than [.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)) by way of [.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

The reason I want to sort the data this way is so that I can visualize the data and changes to it as a image with [.imshow()](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) or something similar.

My concern that this is an improper use of [.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and that the reason I am using Pandas aren't going to work out later, but for the life of me I can't think of another way to do this other than loops which are worse.

Sample of master_df (courtesy of @Alex from below):

```
          B         G         R    X    Y    Z
0  0.206623  0.385774  0.228514  0.0  2.0  0.0
1  0.691172  0.099081  0.338893  0.0  2.0  1.0
2  0.783475  0.238099  0.427903  1.0  2.0  0.0
3  0.241634  0.954246  0.338797  1.0  2.0  1.0
```

Sample output for B_df (X is columns, Z is rows):

```
        0.0    1.0            
0.0  0.206623  0.783475
1.0  0.691172  0.241634
```

Current Code:

```
X = read_from_sql("SELECT DISTINCT X FROM master ORDER BY DESC")

Z = read_from_sql("SELECT DISTINCT Z FROM master ORDER BY DESC")

master_df = read_from_sql("SELECT * FROM master")

def zero_df_creator(index, column):
    '''
    Creates X_df, Y_df, Z_df, R_df, G_df, B_df a dataframe in the shape index x column. All values are zero.

    index = list of index values
    column = list of column values

    Returns: X_df, Y_df, Z_df, R_df, G_df, B_df
    '''

    X_df = pd.Dataframe(0.0, index=index, columns=column)
    Y_df = X_df.copy()
    Z_df = X_df.copy()
    R_df = X_df.copy()
    G_df = X_df.copy()
    B_df = X_df.copy()

    return X_df, Y_df, Z_df, R_df, G_df, B_df


X_df, Y_df, Z_df, R_df, G_df, B_df = zero_df_creator(Z, X)


def set_df_value(df_row):
    '''
    This function sorts XYZRGB values into their respective XZ coordinates for visualization. 
    This function uses pd.set_value due to its speed advantage (roughly twice as fast). 

    If set_value no longer works, change to df.at[index, column] = value  

    Returns: dataframe
    '''


    index = df_row['X']
    column = df_row['Z']

    X_df.set_value(index, column, df_row['X'])
    Y_df.set_value(index, column, df_row['Y'])
    Z_df.set_value(index, column, df_row['Z'])
    R_df.set_value(index, column, df_row['R'])
    G_df.set_value(index, column, df_row['G'])
    B_df.set_value(index, column, df_row['B'])

master_df.apply(set_df_value, axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you post a small sample of `master_df` and what the desired result would be for that small sample?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a DataFrame that looks like:

```
positions = np.vstack(([0, 0, 1, 1], [2] * 4, [0, 1] * 2))
data = np.vstack((positions, np.random.rand(3, 4)))
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip('xyzrgb', data)))

df
```

returns

```
          b         g         r    x    y    z
0  0.206623  0.385774  0.228514  0.0  2.0  0.0
1  0.691172  0.099081  0.338893  0.0  2.0  1.0
2  0.783475  0.238099  0.427903  1.0  2.0  0.0
3  0.241634  0.954246  0.338797  1.0  2.0  1.0
```

Instead of making separate dataframes for each attribute you can just [set the index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to get a useful representation:

```
df.set_index(['x', 'z'])
```

returns

```
                b         g         r    y
x   z                                     
0.0 0.0  0.206623  0.385774  0.228514  2.0
    1.0  0.691172  0.099081  0.338893  2.0
1.0 0.0  0.783475  0.238099  0.427903  2.0
    1.0  0.241634  0.954246  0.338797  2.0
```

Comment: Sorry @Alex, I didn't copy and paste the whole post (specifically the reason for this). However, this is extremely helpful and something I had completely forgotten about. I will definitely be using this.

Comment: @Rusty Glad it worked - Please [mark an answer as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it resolved your question. This helps us keep track of which questions are left to be answered.